# Error when using GDB in Eclipse: "Command '-list-features' is timed out"

Tags: c++, eclipse, debugging, gdb, eclipse-cdt

When I try to debug my c++ program in Eclipse (Neon 4.6.2 on mac), the progress bar stops at 33% and the operation eventually times out. I get an error saying:

Error in services launch sequence -
Command '-list-features' is timed out

I've verified my GDB build and uninstalled and reinstalled using brew multiple times. GDB works perfectly in terminal, but I'm not able to run it in eclipse at all and I greatly prefer having a GUI when debugging. I have ensured that the path to the debugger in the eclipse debug configuration is correct. In addition, I've tried adding -g as a debugging flag.

Any help/suggestions would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a known problem with CDT 9.2, See [Bug 509737](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=509737). It is fixed for 9.2.1 released in a month or so. Your choices are to downgrade CDT to 9.1 or to install the most recent, but unreleased, build of 9.2.1.